# Tracking interactions between users on objects

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set where lots of users have annotated a set of artifacts, and I want to know every other user a user has directly/indirectly interacted with. I want to develop query which shows each user and every other user that contributed to an artifact that they also contributed to. My data looks something like this

```
+----------+------+
| Artifact | User |
+----------+------+
|    1     |   a  |
|    1     |   b  |
|    1     |   c  |
|    1     |   d  |
|    2     |   a  |
|    2     |   m  |
+----------+------+
```

So in this case User a has interacted with b,c,d & m; b has interacted with a,c & d; and m has interacted with a

Ideally it won't show overlaps (so only distinct values), but I can weed through those if necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` function :

```
SELECT 
    t1.User, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.User ORDER BY t2.User) 
FROM 
    test t1
    JOIN test t2 ON (t1.Artifact = t2.Artifact AND t1.User != t2.User)
GROUP BY t1.User
```

[Here's an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14b83/2)

Comment: Ok so this does mostly what I want thanks! But there actually are so many overlaps that it's not showing every relationship, is there a way to remove the duplicates as well (note my tweak to the example code here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14b83/1), where m & b have duplicates

Comment: Here's the updated query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14b83/2, I also updated the answer (added : GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ...)